# Change size of whitespace tab arrow character in VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, tabs, character, whitespace

I am currently setting up VS Code on a new computer and want to maintain all the same configuration, addons etc that I had on my previous computer. I was able to copy all of the settings, fonts, themes I like, etc; however for some reason I can't figure out how to change the size of the Tab arrow character for whitespace.

In my old editor, the Tab arrow spanned two spaces, whereas on my new computer, the tab arrow only spans one space.

I've been looking all over, and tried googling any variation of "change tab character size", "modify tab arrow span" etc that I could think of. I seem to remember changing the arrow size at some years ago, which is how I got it in my old editor, but I've totally forgotten, and can't find the setting anywhere, neither searching in the VS Code settings, nor on google like I mentioned; the only things that turn up are for changing tab indent size from 2, to 4 spaces etc.

Here are some screenshots of what I mean, from the new VS Code editor and from the one on my older computer:

Current tab arrow size in VS Code:

[image: Current tab arrow size in VS Code]

Old tab arrows size (what I want in my new editor):

[image]

This is driving me crazy, and I'm sure it's a simple setting somewhere that I'm missing. Any help would be appreciated!

Edit: In case it is relevant, I'm using JetBrains Mono as my font, and its the same version of the font as from my old computer as well, I copied it over and installed it on the new PC.

Answer (score 0):

To my shock, the issue resolved itself after rebooting my PC. Once again it would seem that the tried and true "have you tried turning it off and on again" continues to ring true in many cases.

The only explanation I can think of is that perhaps some of the font symbols for whitespace characters weren't fully updated for some reason after installing the JetBrains Mono font, which I had installed earlier the same day, and after rebooting my PC I guess all the characters were fully updated/refreshed, and now the longer arrow is displayed for the tabs; I guess this also means that there is no arrow resizing per se, and the arrow symbol for the tab is simply the font symbol.

In any case, I figured I should write this update as an answer in case something like this happens to anyone else in the future.